# Using a variable in the form name of DOM

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

This appears to be something that's easy when you know it but hard to figure out.  The code should be pretty self-explanatory:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<form id='updatenotes_1139' action=index.php method=POST>
<input size=20 type='input' id='b_user' value="Default value">
<input type=submit>
</form>

<script>
var entered = 1139;
var formName = "updatenotes_"+entered;
//alert(formName);  // Displays "updatenotes_1139"
document.forms[formName]b_user.value = "Hello!";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The basic idea is to be able to tell JavaScript what form to edit via a variable.  I can't just use `GetElementByID` because in the full application there are many forms with the same name of input (e.g., 15 forms that each have a "b_user" input).  This is mainly so that the browser's autocomplete will function across all of them (it's just a script for me, so it doesn't have to be pretty so long as it works).

For what it's worth, the `alert` there works just fine.  I just have no idea how to construct the next line, as all the examples I could find online were about using a variable on the input id and not the form id.

Comment: IDs should be unique within a page. You might want to use classes to identify inputs with the same function.

Comment: @blunderboy: `input` elements have no closing tag since they have no content.

Comment: @FelixKling I meant shouldn't we use inputs like this <input type='submit' ... /> It validates our HTML. Isn't it ?

Comment: @blunderboy: It's valid without the self-closing tag. This is only needed for XHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.forms[formName].b_user.value = "Hello!"; 
                     // ^ This is how you'd access it.
```

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fUvvb/1/)

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, and is basically just fixing my syntax.  I added another form with an identical input (ID and name) and this version correctly distinguished the input based on what form it was in.  Given some of the other comments, is there any real issues with this (given that this is just a personal script, not something public that needs massive cross-browser support and whatnot)?

Comment: Just in case someone knows offhand -- do browser autofill histories base their suggestions on ID or name?

Comment: @AlexGold  It may work in this case, but no, each ID you use, should always be unique. Giving the same ID's will cause you to have many problems, in terms of both HTML validation and JavaScript functionality.

Comment: Ah, true that, just curious about the browser thing.  Either way, I shall accept indeed :).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, IDs have to be unique. However, `name`s don't have to be. Change your HTML to:

```
<input size=20 type='input' name='b_user' value="Default value">
```

(or keep the `id` attribute, but you need `name`)

Then you can do:

```
var form = document.getElementById(formName);
var b_user = form.getElementsByName('b_user')[0];
b_user.value = 'Hello';
```

Answer (score 0):

With an id I first tried using this code to access the form via its id

```
document[ "formID" ]; // returned undefined
```

However, when I used the following code it returned the correct form

```
window[ "formID" ]; // returned form element
```

Not really sure whether this is best practice. Anyhow, here is the code I ended up with.

```
var entered = 1139;
var formID = "updatenotes_" + entered;
window[formID].b_user.value = "Hello!";
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/zGHX9/2/)

Comment: What is `formName` name here? A string like in the OP's code or an element?

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for that. Didn't carefully read through the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

DO you want something like this

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<form id='updatenotes_1139' action=index.php method=POST>
<input size=20 type='input' id='b_user' value="Default value">
<input type=submit>
</form>

<script>
var entered = 1139;
var formName = "updatenotes_"+entered;
//alert(formName);  // Displays "updatenotes_1139"
var myForm = document.forms[formName];
  console.log(myForm);
  myForm.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = "Hello!";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Working BIN](http://jsbin.com/abotak/1/edit)**